# Using articles with names

Tags: articles

What article if any should I use in the sentences below?

```
I have -/a/the dog Rex.
I have -/a/the brother Sam.
```

I surmise that in the second case there is no need for an article.
Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In **I have Rex** or **I have Sam**, you don't use articles.

If you're using the word "dog" or "brother", you must use articles.

"**I have a brother, Sam**" means you have a brother called Sam (or that you are speaking to someone called Sam and telling him that you have a brother).

"**I have a dog, Rex**" means you have a dog called Rex.

"**I have the dog, Rex**" means that you have a particular dog that you probably expect the other person to have heard about previously, and that it's called Rex.

Comment: The commas in these examples make them ambiguous. You have noted that in your second example, but the same issue applies to examples 3 and 4. Rex could be a person that you are speaking to about your unnamed dog. If the dog is named Rex, better to say it fully : "I have a dog named Rex." No confusion.